# Xcode Preview canvas different then Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am currently developing an app, and I am trying to setup the Views to be accurate for different screen sizes. I get the design to what I would like in the preview, but then when I run it in the simulator some things are a little off. To note not all screens do this, just a few. Any reason why this may be?

Screenshot for reference: [Xcode/Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtApg.png)

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
//Removed variables for checking log ins and loading screen animation
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        //Check if logged in and not first time
        if status && !firstTime{
            ZStack{
                NavigationView{
                    TabView(){
                        Tab1View()
                            .environmentObject(ContentViewModel())
                        Tab2View()
                            .environmentObject(ContentViewModel())
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                }
                ZStack{
                  //LoadingScreen
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                .onAppear(perform: animateSplash)
                .opacity(endSplash ? 0 : 1)
            }
        } 
          //Check if logged and first time
          else if status && firstTime{
            ZStack{
                NavigationView{
                    if role == "owner"{
                        WelcomeView()
                    } else {
                        WelcomeEmployeeView()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
           NavigationView{
              //View in the screenshot
              CreateView()
           }
        }
    }
```

CreateView:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

struct CreateView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewModel
@State var companyName = ""
@State var employeeName = ""
@State var phoneNumber = ""
@State var show = false
@State var message = ""
@State var alert = false
@State var ID = ""
@State var test = ""
@State var role = "owner"

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack{
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing){
            Path{ path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 80))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:500, y: 180))
            }
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient:Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6470588235, green: 0.8196078431, blue: 0.7450980392, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)), .white, .green]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            Image("icon-white")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 60)
                .padding(.top)
                .padding(.trailing, 30)
        }
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("Create a")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 30))
            Text("Company Account")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 30))
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                
            
            Text("Company Name")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Semibold", size: 16))
            TextField("", text: $companyName)
                .frame(width: 290)
                .padding(14)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).strokeBorder(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5)))
                .padding(.bottom)

            
            Text("Employee Name")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Semibold", size: 16))
            TextField("", text: $employeeName)
                .frame(width: 290)
                .padding(14)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).strokeBorder(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5)))
                .padding(.bottom)
            
            Text("Phone Number")
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)))
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Semibold", size: 16))
            TextField("", text: $phoneNumber)
                .frame(width: 290)
                .padding(14)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).strokeBorder(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5)))
                .padding(.bottom)
            
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: VerifcationView(show: $show, ID: $ID, name: $employeeName, companyName: $companyName, phoneNumber: $phoneNumber, hasCode: $test, role: $role), isActive: $show){
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.8588235294, alpha: 1)))
                            .frame(width: 315,height: 50)
                        Button(action: {
                            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber( "+"+self.phoneNumber, uiDelegate:nil){ (ID, error) in
                                
                                if error != nil {
                                    self.message = (error?.localizedDescription)!
                                    self.alert.toggle()
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                self.ID = ID!
                                self.show.toggle()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Create Account")
                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 18))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: JoinView()){
                    Text("Join as Employee")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 141/255, green: 141/255, blue: 141/255))
                        .underline(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/true/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, color: Color(red: 141/255, green: 141/255, blue: 141/255))
                }
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .padding(.top)
        
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably have your view embedded in another view in your final app, which your simulator runs. Can you show your code?

Comment: @aheze Sadly I can not post my code due to background agreements. But you are correct it  is being affected from a parent view. I assume my best bet would be to look into GeometryReader to resolve this?

Comment: No, avoid `GeometryReader` as much as possible. Also, if you could make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be really helpful

Comment: @aheze Ok I have updated with an example of the ContentView, can add CreateView example if needed as well

Comment: What's `status`, `firstTime`, and `ContentViewModel`? And yeah add `CreateView` if you can

Comment: @aheze status, firstTime and ContentViewModel were just state variables and EnvironmentObject used to show the load screen and handle the state. I have updated with CreateView code

Comment: If you have preview data available, then you should be able to pin the parent view in the simulator, and then make changes in the child view. That being said, you should not try to force things in position with frames, etc. You can also preview on multiple devices at once: [How to preview your layout in different devices](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-preview-your-layout-in-different-devices).

Comment: Actually did not know you could preview multiple devices at a time, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SwiftUI previews, you just preview a single view - `CreateView`. This is the **only** view that gets previewed. Meanwhile, your simulator runs the entire app, starting all the way back from your `ContentView`.

Note that inside `ContentView`, you're wrapping `CreateView` in a `NavigationView`.

```
NavigationView{
    // View in the screenshot
    CreateView()
}
```

This will add a gap at the top of the screen, pushing everything else down (resulting in the difference that you see). Even the `icon-white` image is pushed down into the white part of the screen, which is why you can't see it in the simulator.

Comment: What would be the best approach to still use the NavigationView and have it not push everything down?

Comment: @Lowgy you could hide it: `CreateView().navigationBarHidden(true)`.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't realize this before. Appreciate the help!